# Garamond and URL links

Tags: fonts, typography, typewriter

I am experimenting the use of the Garamond Premier Pro font for a dissertation and I still would like to keep the URL information in the bibliography when available. Obviously, there's a font problem since the typewriter family through `\texttt` does not really fit well. Would you have a suggestion to fix or improve this?

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to use a typewriter font for the URL? It is a common choice, but nothing makes it compulsory and perhaps would you be better off with a humanist sans serif contrasting font or something like that. I doubt a monospaced font would ever look good besides an old-style serif like Garamond.

Comment: yes, you are right, this could be changed. I'll have a look at how this can be achieved.

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I am using XeLaTeX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your URL font does not seem to fit well with Garamond because the letter has a small x-height (height of lowercase letters like "a, c, e"). I suggest to use a sans serif or typewriter font which either has about the same x-height as Garamond or can be scaled via a LaTeX package -- Helvetica (with the `helvet` package) is an example of the latter.

As I don't own Garamond Premier Pro, the following example shows how to scale Helvetica so that its x-height about matches that of Times (`mathptmx` package).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{helvet}

\begin{document}

\huge

Some text in roman \textsf{and sans serif.}

\bigskip

Times' x-height: \the\fontdimen5\font

\sffamily

Helvetica's x-height: \the\fontdimen5\font

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I could probably directly achieve this with the proper definition of the sans-serif font with `XeLaTeX`.